# Socket.io with Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, socket.io

This works perfectly on my own computers server

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.of(userid).on('email', function (data) {
      console.log("here")
});
```

however when I switch to heroku like

```
var socket = io.connect('http://staginggorkemnutrition.herokuapp.com');
    socket.of(userid).on('email', function (data) {
      console.log("here")
});
```

it seems like the event is never received, also I dont change anything on my server when I am changing from heroku to localhost

ps.
I have this in my server, I know I have to add this for heroku
    global.io.configure(function () { 
      global.io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
      global.io.set("polling duration", 10); 
    });

and my server side code when I emit the message looks like looks like:

```
exports.getFake = function(req, res){
    global.io.of(global.id).emit('email' , email);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Web socket is experimental on Heroku.
Did you read this : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-labs-websockets ?
You may want to read this too : [heroku multiple dyno socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191958/heroku-multiple-dyno-socket-io)